# iOS - Displaying a static view across an application

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to achieve the following:
[image]

What would be the best way to implement this? The static views won't be a part of the transitions/animations either. Meaning that when the user goes from VC1 -> VC2 the subviews should be displaying the same information throughout the transition of the views.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify your situation more?  If you want to keep the static portion across controllers without animation swap, it doesn't seem likely since in the object hierarchy, views sit inside controllers so one swap gets them all.

Unless you really need 3  controllers, may i suggest a work around which is to stack three swappable subviews in one UIView and then the static subviews in another. When you swap the swappable views only those will change and not the static one.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was going for keeping a static portion. Plus it doesn't have to be three it could be more views but that portion should be static on all the views. Also, I'm using a tabbar controller so I think I would have to change my view/code around considerably to implement this. You solution does seem practical though.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a similar static subview by implementing;

1- An UIViewController subclass containing the static subview

2- Force set navigation controller's transition animated to NO

3- Implemeting your own transition (by shifting the view controller's main view to left or right)

Comment: I will give this a try. I already have a subview controller that has a UIVIewController subclass, the problem is that I am using a tab bar view controller for my other views. Any suggestions on implementing your method on a tab bar view controller?

Comment: since I used my static subview as a tabbar/toolbar I did not implemented a tabbar with it. Actually, I cannot see a way to make them both available since your subview will look like a navigation controller on the bottom, you cannot shift it up, and cannot shift the tabbar as well